# Parse encoded url with regex

Tags: regex

I have the following URL

`https://example.com/external-image/http://www.thirdpartyexample.com/TWM/param/param/param/image.jpg`

encoded it looks like this

`https://example.com/external-image/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thirdpartyexample.com%2FTWM%2Fparam%2Fparam%2Fparam%2Fimage.jpg`

I'm trying to parse everything after external-image.

**My goal is for $1** = `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thirdpartyexample.com%2FTWM%2Fparam%2Fparam%2Fparam%2Fimage.jpg`

**And $2** = thirdpartyexample.com

My regex thus far.

```
^.*?\/external-image\/((?:https?[%3A][%2F][%2F])?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:[%2F]\n]+).*)$
```

and my non working example can be found here https://regex101.com/r/qL3qT7/1

Working regex when the url is not encoded.

```
^.*?\/external-image\/((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+).*)$
```

What do I need to do in order to get regex to recongize the encoded parameters? I thought maybe grouping them would work, but that has not seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this (based on the input/output you've given):

```
.+external-image\/((?:https?%3A%2F%2F)?(?:www\.)?(.+?\..+?)%2F.+)
```

It'll match up to the beginning of the part of the URL you care about, use an optional protocol string, then put the base URL you care about in `$1` and the full (encoded) URL in `$2`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Appears to work perfectly.

Comment: @CodeJunkie: One small mistake in where I placed the capture group for `$1`. Should be fixed now.